# Why do many cli applications seem to crash?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, macos, homebrew

Latest MacBook Pro 512GB 2017.

For example:

```
$ php
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

It did start since I ran Ccleaner yesterday, but I'm running a 64-bit version and not of Windows, so surely that's not related?

It seems that mostly, but not exclusively brew installed applications are affected.

```
Process:               php [79030]
Path:                  /usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.20_12/bin/php
Identifier:            php
Version:               0
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        bash [78809]
Responsible:           php [79030]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-09-20 16:47:24.210 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G29)
Report Version:        12

Time Awake Since Boot: 940000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       37000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
       0x10fe1e000 -        0x11079effb +php (0) <80DC9E50-D749-366A-BC44-517201E78D84> /usr/local/bin/php
       0x11095d000 -        0x110acd727 +libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (0) <11B495A9-782C-3FB0-9729-ACFCD9F4F53E> /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
       0x110b48000 -        0x110b89ff7 +libssl.1.0.0.dylib (0) <35C152E0-7168-3B99-94AB-ECA04D3B3DB5> /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
       0x110bae000 -        0x110bd1ff3 +libreadline.7.dylib (0) <E16A5AF1-953F-3274-BFBA-725FD9973D8D> /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
       0x110beb000 -        0x110bf3ff3 +libintl.8.dylib (0) <9A1967E0-AC59-3EF6-B14F-643AF08A6B4F> /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib
       0x110bfe000 -        0x110c21ffb +libpng16.16.dylib (0) <949DC3DD-DB87-3DE9-9615-FCF16DCBAC61> /usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
       0x11f841000 -        0x11f87edc7  dyld (433.5) <322C06B7-8878-311D-888C-C8FD2CA96FF3> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff81931000 -     0x7fff81967fff  com.apple.LDAPFramework (2.4.28 - 194.5) <492ACA22-373E-3DD9-BAEB-9EF6AA962FD5> /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP
    0x7fff9303b000 -     0x7fff93047ffb  libexslt.0.dylib (15.9) <0FEE938A-AD8C-344A-8240-32550E0B9C7B> /usr/lib/libexslt.0.dylib
    0x7fff93050000 -     0x7fff93142ff7  libiconv.2.dylib (50) <42125B35-81D7-3FC4-9475-A26DBE10884D> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    0x7fff9364a000 -     0x7fff9367bffb  libncurses.5.4.dylib (51.30.1) <B03B1BD2-7080-3856-BB02-7E8238320C3B> /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib
    0x7fff93b1f000 -     0x7fff93b3bffb  libresolv.9.dylib (64) <A244AE4C-00B0-396C-98FF-97FE4DB3DA30> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
    0x7fff93ef6000 -     0x7fff93f07ff3  libz.1.dylib (67) <46E3FFA2-4328-327A-8D34-A03E20BFFB8E> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
```

Also node is affected the same way:

```
$ node
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.58.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node
  Reason: image not found
```

Error on screen:

```
Process:               node [79078]
Path:                  /usr/local/Cellar/node/8.1.2/bin/node
Identifier:            node
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        bash [78809]
Responsible:           node [79078]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-09-20 16:51:15.877 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G29)
Report Version:        12

Time Awake Since Boot: 940000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       37000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.58.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x100e845df +node (???) <95A4D949-1196-3BB6-A361-8196E3D6972B> /usr/local/bin/node
       0x104e27000 -        0x104e64dc7  dyld (433.5) <322C06B7-8878-311D-888C-C8FD2CA96FF3> /usr/lib/dyld

Model: MacBookPro14,3, BootROM MBP143.0160.B02, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2,9 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.45f0
Graphics: kHW_AMDRadeonPro560Item, Radeon Pro 560, PCIe, 4096 MB
Graphics: kHW_IntelHDGraphics630Item, Intel HD Graphics 630, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x802C, 0x4D5435324C31473332443450472D30393320
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x802C, 0x4D5435324C31473332443450472D30393320
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x173), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.130.1a1)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.5f1, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: iBridge
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.2
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.2
```

I ran the suggested brew commands:

```
$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
  /usr/local/lib/libjson-c.2.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libykclient.3.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libykpers-1.1.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libyubikey.0.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/python2.7/greenlet/greenlet.h
  /usr/local/include/python3.6m/greenlet/greenlet.h


Warning: Some installed formula are missing dependencies.
You should `brew install` the missing dependencies:
  brew install graphviz libcroco librsvg

Run `brew missing` for more details.
```

Comment: Just at first glance, you have a common error - `dylib`.  See this Q/A:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703296/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-lib-libjpeg-8-dylib-homebrew-php

Answer (score 2):

Something either moved or removed libraries from your disk, or replaced a library version without updating its dependencies. See if `brew switch jpeg 8d` works and fixes the problem. If not, the easiest course of action – although a bit of a shotgun approach – is to reinstall all installed homebrew packages, which you can do by running

```
brew list | xargs brew reinstall
```

in the terminal. You can also reinstall only those packages you are having trouble with (with `brew reinstall <package>`, but you should not have to reinstall Homebrew itself.

You *might* be able to fix it by running the commands suggested by `brew`, namely:

```
brew install graphviz libcroco librsvg
```

but it seems that your binaries were linked against a version of libjpeg &c. installed through some other means, so a clean reinstall would probably be the best course of action.

Answer (score 1):

```
brew reinstall php@7.0 # Swap PHP version as needed.
```

I had to re-install the custom PHP modules I had previously installed after I ran this command.